# The problem with getting the result in the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, qr-code

Good day, I'm trying to get the result of scanning the QR code in the fragment, as activity everything works, but after the transfer the result cannot be obtained. How can this be fixed?

As I understood the problem in the "onActivityResult" method. I need to some information for solution. how can  change it for the fragment ?

My Code is below line:

```
public class Fragment_qr extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button btnScanQRCode;
private TextView txtFruit, txtSize, txtColor;

//QR Code Scanner Object
private IntentIntegrator qrScan;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.qr_code_scan_layout, null);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    btnScanQRCode = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnScanQRCode);
    txtFruit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtFruitName);
    txtSize = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtFruitSize);
    txtColor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtFruitColor);

    //Initialize the Scan Object
    qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());

    //OnClickListener Attached to the Button
    btnScanQRCode.setOnClickListener(this);

}

//Getting the scan results
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        //Check to see if QR Code has nothing in it
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //QR Code contains some data
            try {
                //Convert the QR Code Data to JSON
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                //Set up the TextView Values using the data from JSON
                txtFruit.setText(obj.getString("fruit"));
                txtSize.setText(obj.getString("size"));
                txtColor.setText(obj.getString("color"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //In case of exception, display whatever data is available on the QR Code
                //This can be caused due to the format MisMatch of the JSON
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                txtSize.setText(result.getContents());
                System.out.println("code QR: " + result.getContents());
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    //initiating the qr code scan
    qrScan.initiateScan();

}
}
```

Comment: `super.onActivityResult` should place right after `onActivityResult` function

Comment: @JohnJoe, 
Why is onActivityResult worth posting like this?

Comment: Where are you calling `startActivityForResult()`? If you want to consume activity results in a fragment, you need to call it on that particular fragment.

Comment: @DominikG. 
where to add it? In the event "onClick"?

Comment: Yes, just call `startActivityForResult` there and give it the parameters you give it otherwise, then the result should be delivered.

Comment: @DominikG.
And what parameters should be? Sorry for the inconvenience of asking questions)

Answer (score 2):

This replacement helped:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this).initiateScan();
   }
```